# What is the meaning of Go/Gin debug output - (x handlers)

Tags: go, go-gin

In the following Go/Gin debug output, what is the meaning of (5 handlers). As you can see, I obviously have more than 5 handlers.

```
[GIN-debug] GET    /                         --> .../handlers.APIDetail (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /signup                   --> .../handlers.SignUp (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /signin                   --> .../handlers.SignIn (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /refresh-token            --> .../handlers.RefreshToken (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /verify-email             --> .../handlers.VerifyEmailVerificationToken (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /resend-verification-email --> .../handlers.ResendEmailVerificationEmail (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /reset-password           --> .../handlers.ResetPassword (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /change-password          --> .../handlers.ChangePassword (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] PATCH  /users/me                 --> .../handlers.UpdateProfile (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /signout                  --> .../handlers.SignOut (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /orgs/:id                 --> .../handlers.GetOrganizations (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /orgs                     --> .../handlers.GetOrganizations (5 handlers)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the number of handlers in each route's **handler chain**, i.e. the maximum number of handlers, including middleware, that will be executed when a request is routed to a certain endpoint.

Relevant code from [Gin sources @latest](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/debug.go#L26):

```
func debugPrintRoute(httpMethod, absolutePath string, handlers HandlersChain) {
    if IsDebugging() {
        nuHandlers := len(handlers)
        handlerName := nameOfFunction(handlers.Last())
        if DebugPrintRouteFunc == nil {
            debugPrint("%-6s %-25s --> %s (%d handlers)\n", httpMethod, absolutePath, handlerName, nuHandlers)
        } else {
            DebugPrintRouteFunc(httpMethod, absolutePath, handlerName, nuHandlers)
        }
    }
}
```

If you are setting a few global middlewares, e.g. with `router.Use`, before declaring the routes, and no route has per-route middlewares, that explains why the number is always the same.

For example, consider the following:

```
    r.Use(func(*gin.Context) { fmt.Println("FIRST") })
    r.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Status(http.StatusOK)
    })

    r.Use(func(*gin.Context) { fmt.Println("SECOND") })
    r.GET("/bar", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Status(http.StatusOK)
    })
```

This prints:

```
[GIN-debug] GET    /foo    --> main.main.func2 (2 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /bar    --> main.main.func4 (3 handlers)
```

Because `/foo`'s chain has the `FIRST` middleware, and the handler itself (2), and `/bar`'s chain has both `FIRST` and `SECOND` middleware, plus the handler itself (3).

Comment: Thank you. Your example is straight forward. However, in my code, I have a couple of 'Use's before my routes are declared. I expected the handlers counts to increase with each handler declaration, but it didn't. So, does the count indicate how many handlers Gin needs to check, at runtime, before it reaches that particular handler for execution.

Comment: yeah, as I said, it's the count of handlers in *that route's handlers chain*, i.e. how many handlers the Gin engine will invoke when you request one of those resources. If you call `r.Use(foo)`, `r.Use(bar)` then `r.GET(...)` and `r.POST(...)` both get and post will invoke 3 handlers. If you call POST, it won't also call GET.